# How to start or continue with tasks using a event as a trigger in task parallel library

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, task-parallel-library, task

this is my first post here so please let me know if i am framing my question the right way while following the rules.

I recently started learning c# and stumbled upon TPL for multi-threading in WPF using MVVM.
The grid is bound to a ObservableCollection in ViewModel as seen in the figure.

[image: DataGrid bound to a observable collection in viewmodel]

The first column is stepnumber, the second column is a checkbox (which I want to use as a waiting condition to go to the next step), the third column is time and the fourth column is the function call. I am trying to code the following logic.

Step 1 thread starts at 0 secs and calls corresponding Function A.

After 5secs(0+5) step 2 thread starts and calls corresponding Function B.

After 15secs (5+10) step 3 thread starts and calls corresponding Function C.

Now since I have a checkbox next to step 4, I have to wait for certain event (track a signal in another thread and find if a threshold is met) or till a maximum timeout period and continue with the rest of the steps.

I have created the Tasks using the below logic, (code snip only)

```
     int currStepTime, prevStepTime = 0;
     foreach (var data in DataCollection)
        {
         int temp = currStepTime;
          if(data.FunctionType == "A")
         {
         aTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => FunctionA(temp,cts));
         currStepTime = currStepTime + data.StepTime
         }
         else if(data.FunctionType == "B")
         {
         bTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => FunctionB(temp,cts));
         currStepTime = currStepTime + data.StepTime
         }
         else if(data.FunctionType == "C")
         {
         cTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => FunctionC(temp,cts));
         currStepTime = currStepTime + data.StepTime
         }
        }

  private  async void FunctionA(int stepTime,CancellationTokenSource cts)
    {
     if (cts.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
               Console.WriteLine("Task Cancelled");
            }
            try
            {
                await Task.Delay(stepTime * 1000,cts.Token); 
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("catch task cancel");
            } 
            cts = null;
    }
```

Currently I am not able to find out what I should be using to wait for the trigger event during step 4 and continue with the rest of my steps.

Edit:

I am still trying to figure out how to know which checkbox is selected, so meanwhile the selected row items (by setting SelectionMode = "Single" it will allow user to select only one column) is found by defining the following interaction behavior and I manually select the 4th row.

```
<telerik:RadGridView x:Name="MyGrid" SelectionMode="Single" SelectedItem=" {Binding SelectedDataGrid,Mode=TwoWay}" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}"  NewRowPosition="Bottom" GroupRenderMode="Flat" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="353" Width="400" Margin="563,7,37,0" >
<i:Interaction.Behaviors>
<pressure:MyMultiSelectBehavior SelectedItems="{Binding SelectedItems,Source={StaticResource myViewModel}}"/>
</i:Interaction.Behaviors>
<telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
<telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Step Number" DataMemberBinding="{Binding StepNumber, Mode=TwoWay}"></telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
<telerik:GridViewCheckBoxColumn Header="Checkbox" DataMemberBinding="{Binding IsActive}" AutoSelectOnEdit="True" EditTriggers="CellClick" />
<telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Time" DataMemberBinding="{Binding StepTime, Mode=TwoWay}"></telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
<telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Function Call" DataMemberBinding="{Binding MyFunctionCall, Mode=TwoWay}"></telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
</telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
</telerik:RadGridView>
```

I have defined a property in ViewModel which gives the number of the selected row as below,

```
public MyDataGrid SelectedDataGrid
  {
   get { return this.selectedDataGrid; }
   set
    {
   if (this.selectedDataGrid != value)
      {
     this.selectedDataGrid = value;
     this.OnPropertyChanged("SelectedDataGrid");
      }
    }
  }
```

Any thoughts or resources about solving this problem would be really helpful for me. Please let me know if more details are needed.

Comment: One primitive solution would be using a while(!var){} call until said "var", would be set to true, meaning it could progress. As you can see I'm not exactly knowledgeable with async computing, only tip I can give, maybe somebody else knows a more practical solution.

Comment: please show us what happens when you change the checkbox value (i.e. what event/binding you are using)

Comment: @slawekwin I have added more code that I hope will explain how i find if a row is selected (4 for example). The SelectedDataGrid has StepNumber property which i am intending to use to get the index of the selected step number.